# Figures don't get centered when redefining title page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tufte

I'm using the `tufte-book` class. If I redefine the `\maketitlepage` command, the figures stop getting centered. Here's a MWE reproducing the issue:

```
\documentclass[justified, symmetric, titlepage]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx, lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\fontsize{15}{15}\scshape\@author\par}
\vspace{5cm}
{\fontsize{37}{37}\scshape\@title}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

And this is the (unwanted) result

[image]

Comment: As you can see, the class becomes thoroughly confused and page 2 is considered as a right-hand page, but the figure is still considered to be on a left-hand page.

Comment: @egreg Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you write an bug report on the tufte web page please.

Please see the following a little bit changed code (important here I added option `debug` and I added some more text around the figure to be able to show the culprit with some more changings (uncommenting more text)):

```
\documentclass[%
  justified, 
  symmetric, 
  titlepage,
  debug       % <=======================================================
]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{graphicx, lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\fontsize{15}{15}\scshape\@author\par}
\vspace{5cm}
{\fontsize{37}{37}\scshape\@title}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-4]

Now follows figure in code. % <=========================================
%Now follows figure in code. % <========================================
%Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 
%Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 
%Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 
%Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 
%Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} % [width=0.4\textwidth]
\caption{figure}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

This is text after the figure in code. % <==============================
This is text after the figure in code. 
This is text after the figure in code. This is text after the figure in code. 
This is text after the figure in code. This is text after the figure in code. 
This is text after the figure in code. This is text after the figure in code. 
This is text after the figure in code. This is text after the figure in code. 

\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Then you get the same layout you have

[image: layout]

but in the log file you can find following:

[image: debug info]

As you can see the culprit is that the wrong page number `odd` instead of `even` is recognized.

To get rid of that you can uncoment the commented lines to get the code:

```
\documentclass[%
  justified, 
  symmetric, 
  titlepage,
  debug       % <=======================================================
]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{graphicx, lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\fontsize{15}{15}\scshape\@author\par}
\vspace{5cm}
{\fontsize{37}{37}\scshape\@title}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-4]

Now follows figure in code. % <=========================================
Now follows figure in code. % <========================================
Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 
Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 
Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 
Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 
Now follows figure in code. Now follows figure in code. 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} % [width=0.4\textwidth]
\caption{figure}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

This is text after the figure in code. % <==============================
This is text after the figure in code. 
This is text after the figure in code. This is text after the figure in code. 
This is text after the figure in code. This is text after the figure in code. 
This is text after the figure in code. This is text after the figure in code. 
This is text after the figure in code. This is text after the figure in code. 

\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

As you can see here

[image: page layout]

the figure is centered, because the workaround moves the text around the figure to page 2. That allows a correct recognizing of used page you can see in the debug info:

[image]

So moving manually the code for the figure down or up can solve the culprit, but it is no automatic thing. To get the automatic back add the bug report to tufte web site.

Comment: It seems like the issue has already been reported, [here](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/issues/51) and [here](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/issues/127). The class was last updated four years ago, which tells me it isn't very well maintained .

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using manual markings with `\forcerectofloat` and `\forceversofloat`, I successfully tried a solution described in the documentation of the `ifoddpage` package:

```
%\usepackage{ifoddpage}% works also without this package
...
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@tufte@checkoddpage}{%
   \leavevmode \hbox \bgroup
   \checkoddpage
   \egroup
   \ifoddpage%
      \setboolean{@tufte@odd@page}{true}%
   \else%
      \setboolean{@tufte@odd@page}{false}%
   \fi%
}%
\makeatother
```

I have neither checked for side-effects nor have I tested other examples. However, it may be a good point to start with.