# Margin reversed on figure in tufte-book

Tags: margins, tufte

*I'm sorry, but I'm getting a bit desperate about this.  I've been working on a camera-ready book for quite a long time, my publisher finds that the margin errors arising in tufte-book make my manuscript unacceptable.  I've posted a bug report but it has elicited no reply.  I've tried using `changepage`, as recommended.  Nothing has worked.*

I'm writing a book in tufte-book and occasionally get figures and captions that do not respect which side the margin is on.  Here, on page 24, the margin is on the left (as can be seen by the \quote text below), but the figure and caption are incorrectly placed as if the margin were on the right.

I've typeset the document many (e.g., five) times in a row, expecting that settings and orientations would be corrected, but it the error remains.

I'm sorry but I cannot create a minimal example as it would involve many many pages of commands and such.

Hence my question is rather general:  How can one force the left-right setting for a figure in tufte-book?

[image: Tufte-book with margin flipped]

Thanks to the creator of Tufte-book.sty I learned of \forceversofloat and \forcerectofloat, to be placed inside a figure environment, which force a figure to place the caption on the left or right.  This is a big help *when the final document is ready*.  However, if you insert these commands and *then* edit your text leading to figures changing places, then you have to go back and switch them by hand for the new page symmetry.

I'm going to try to write a function using \if to use the correct forcing command on even and on odd pages.

---

Addendum:

```
\checkoddpage \ifoddpage \forcerectofloat \else \forceversofloat \fi
```

works when I typeset the *entire* book at a time but not when I typeset just one chapter at a time.

Comment: Seems to be the bug I descibed in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476683/16550

Comment: Ah... essentially the same problem (but I didn't find it because it involved centering).  I'll submit a bug report to tufte-book and hope for the best!  Thanks.

Comment: The `changepage` package provides a robust means of checking for even/odd pages, which is the problem here. I have no idea if it would be compatible with `tufte`.

Comment: @PeterWilson:  Thanks... but changing the page parity will not solve the problem, because it is the inconsistency *on a single page* that is at issue.

Comment: This looks like it could have to do with https://texfaq.org/FAQ-oddpage as Peter Wilson already mentioned. The `tufte-latex` classes actually make use of `\checkoddpage`, but only if the package `changepage` or `chngpage` is installed (though the actual definitions make me suspect one would get an error in case neither of the two packages is present). So *in theory* the class looks like it would do the right thing.

Comment: @David G. Stork - Did you ever manage to come up with a satisfactory solution to the problem you describe here? I have just encountered the same problem. I have tried some of the suggestions found elsewhere on this site but all to no avail.

Comment: @omegadot.  You caught me at just the moment I was dealing with this!  I put the following line within each figure environment,  `\checkoddpage \ifoddpage \forcerectofloat \else \forceversofloat \fi`, and it works fine *if and only if* I typeset the *whole* book.  Somehow the page parity and such gets properly passed in that case.  (Try it.)  If, however, I typeset just *one* chapter at a time, then I come across problems... some figures work, others not.  If you manage how to fix this for single chapters, by all means post your solution.  I--and many others--will be so grateful.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David. This seems to me the best work around solution I have found. It works in that it places the figure captions on the correct side of the margin. Of course, as you say, this only works if the entire book is typeset in one go.